# Data retrieve using entity framework issue in dotnet core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have a table with user answers.Assume survey contains 5 questions.Then this row contains 5 rows per user.I want to retrive it like

```
userEmail: 'amara@gmail.com',
              qustns: []
```

Here is the json data what I want.

```
 uersSurveyAnswers: any = [
        {
          userEmail: 'amara@gmail.com',
          qustns: [
            {
              qNo: 1,
              ansrs: ['1']
            },
            {
              qNo: 2,
              ansrs: ['1', '0', '1', '1']
            },
            {
              qNo: 5,
              ansrs: ['2']
            },
            {
              qNo: 6,
              ansrs: ['0', '1', '1', '0']
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          userEmail: 'saman@gmail.com',
          qustns: [
            {
              qNo: 1,
              ansrs: ['3']
            },
            {
              qNo: 2,
              ansrs: ['0', '0', '1', '1']
            },
            {
              qNo: 5,
              ansrs: ['1']
            },
            {
              qNo: 6,
              ansrs: ['1', '1', '0', '0']
            }
          ]
        }]
```

But it returns like this

```
[
    {
        "userEmail": "amara@gmail.com",
        "qustns": [
            {
                "qNo": 1,
                "ansrs": [
                    "2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 2,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 3,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "4",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 4,
                "ansrs": [
                    "Blue"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userEmail": "amara@gmail.com",
        "qustns": [
            {
                "qNo": 1,
                "ansrs": [
                    "2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 2,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 3,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "4",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 4,
                "ansrs": [
                    "Blue"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userEmail": "amara@gmail.com",
        "qustns": [
            {
                "qNo": 1,
                "ansrs": [
                    "2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 2,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 3,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "4",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 4,
                "ansrs": [
                    "Blue"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userEmail": "amara@gmail.com",
        "qustns": [
            {
                "qNo": 1,
                "ansrs": [
                    "2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 2,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 3,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "4",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 4,
                "ansrs": [
                    "Blue"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userEmail": "saman@gmail.com",
        "qustns": [
            {
                "qNo": 1,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 2,
                "ansrs": [
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 3,
                "ansrs": [
                    "2",
                    "1",
                    "4",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 4,
                "ansrs": [
                    "Green"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userEmail": "saman@gmail.com",
        "qustns": [
            {
                "qNo": 1,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 2,
                "ansrs": [
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 3,
                "ansrs": [
                    "2",
                    "1",
                    "4",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 4,
                "ansrs": [
                    "Green"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userEmail": "saman@gmail.com",
        "qustns": [
            {
                "qNo": 1,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 2,
                "ansrs": [
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 3,
                "ansrs": [
                    "2",
                    "1",
                    "4",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 4,
                "ansrs": [
                    "Green"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userEmail": "saman@gmail.com",
        "qustns": [
            {
                "qNo": 1,
                "ansrs": [
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 2,
                "ansrs": [
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 3,
                "ansrs": [
                    "2",
                    "1",
                    "4",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "qNo": 4,
                "ansrs": [
                    "Green"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Here is my code

```
var qstns = await (from uans in _context.UserAnswers
                                   where uans.SurveyId == id
                                   select new UserAnswersReturnDto
                                   {
                                       UserEmail = uans.CreatedBy,
                                       Qustns = (from ans in _context.UserAnswers
                                                  where ans.CreatedBy == uans.CreatedBy 
                                                  select new UserAnswersSet
                                       {
                                           QNo = ans.QNo,
                                           Ansrs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ans.Answers) ? "[]" : ans.Answers)
                                       }).ToArray() 

                                   }).ToListAsync();
```

How to resolve this issue.
here is my table view screen.
I think this issue will resolve if I add group by.But I tried it.I can't understand how to use it.please help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your json sample with `uersSurveyAnswers: any = [...]` isn't valid. I guess you meant `uersSurveyAnswers: [...]`.

What you are looking for in this case is making an object that contains your collection of `UserAnswersReturnDto`. You can simply return the following to do this:

```
return new { uersSurveyAnswers = qstns };
```

Comment: Thank you for your repIy.Actually I want to get data from database.uersSurveyAnswers  array is what I expected result